# How to add .dcproj into solution via dotnet sdk

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, asp.net-core-cli

I have a solution named: `MyProject.sln` and project related to docker called - `docker-compose.dcproj`.

I want to create dotnet new template which will contain support for docker-compose through project `docker-compose.dcproj`.

I tried this command:

`dotnet sln MyProject.sln add docker-compose.dcproj`

I got this error message:

> Project 'C:\MyProject\docker-compose.dcproj' has an unknown project type and cannot be added to the solution file. Contact your SDK provider for support.

I am using `.net core sdk` version `3.1.100`.

How to add `docker-compose.dcproj` into solution via command above?

Answer (score 10):

You can overcome this issue using VS, Refer the image below. This will generate the docker-compose.yml file in the root of the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I was able to get it to working at least two ways.

#### 1. Visual Studio

I created a .net framework project. Right clicked on Project. Add > Docker Support.
I moved

1. docker-compose.dcproj
2. docker-compose.override.yml
3. docker-compose.yml

to a .NET Core project folder.

Select Added new project and picked up this dcproj file.
With a few edits to the compose file. I was able to get it to working.

#### 2. When you don't have visual studio.

I see the mentioned error too. Not able to add the project through cli

```
$ dotnet sln ConsoleApp2.sln add "docker-compose.dcproj"
Project 'C:\Code\ConsoleApp2\docker-compose.dcproj' has an unknown project type and cannot be added to the solution file. Contact your SDK provider for support.
```

I modified the sln file text as below.

$ type docker-compose.dcproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.Docker.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectVersion>2.1</ProjectVersion>
    <DockerTargetOS>Windows</DockerTargetOS>
    <ProjectGuid>9c31f76d-0249-4004-9b65-d5fa07cf95f8</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="docker-compose.override.yml">
      <DependentUpon>docker-compose.yml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="docker-compose.yml" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Add below two lines above `Global` in the solution file.

```
Project("{Any GUID}") = "docker-compose", "docker-compose.dcproj", "{<ProjectGuid> from above output}"
EndProject
```

Please do not mess up the file format. Be very careful. Save a copy of solution file before you attempt any of this. Good luck.